# HighCharts Glow Effect on Charts Doesnt not affect to multiple graphs

Tags: highcharts

So, I am making a glowing effect to the Charts

But only the first Chart is showing the effects, and all other tables are invisible (Data is loaded but graph is invisible).

When I comment out the glowing effect part from css, everything went smooth again.

All other charts have exactly the same setting, but somehow (#glow) just doesn’t apply to the other three charts. Can you help me out please?
Really appreciated!

This is the link where I get the code setting from for filter: url(#glow):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/shadow/
```

And this is the link where I reproduced the problem:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/x6eg4ka7/20/
```

```
//JavaScript
$("#First").on("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("container2").style.display = "none";
  var BTCstockChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
      time: {
          timezone: 'America/New_York'
      },
      chart: {
          styledMode: true
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Price',
              style: {
                  color: '#FFF'
              }
          },
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#b5ffb5'
              }
          }
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
              minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
              hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
              day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
              week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
              month: '%Y-%m',
              year: '%Y'
          },
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#b5ffb5'
              }
          }
      },
          rangeSelector: {
          allButtonsEnabled: true,
          inputEnabled: false,
          buttonSpacing: 8,
          labelStyle: {
              color: '#f7d3d3'
          },
          buttons: [{
              type: 'day',
              count: 1,
              text: '1D',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      BTCstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 70.9],
                          [1562559400000, 10],
                          [1562560400000, 50.9],
                          [1562561400000, 20.9],
                          [1562562400000, 100.9],
                          [1562563400000, 40.9],
                          [1562564400000, 60.9],
                          [1562565400000, 29.9]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          },{
              type: 'day',
              count: 3,
              text: '3D',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      BTCstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 74.9],
                          [1562559400000, 1],
                          [1562560400000, 30.9],
                          [1562561400000, 25.9],
                          [1562562400000, 29.9],
                          [1562563400000, 58.9],
                          [1562564400000, 29],
                          [1562565400000, 68.90]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          }, {
              type: 'all',
              text: 'All',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      BTCstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 29.9],
                          [1562559400000, 50],
                          [1562560400000, 80.9],
                          [1562561400000, 100.9],
                          [1562562400000, 10.9],
                          [1562563400000, 30.9],
                          [1562564400000, 50.9],
                          [1562565400000, 29.9]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          }]
      },
      navigator: {
          enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
          enabled: false
      },

      legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },

      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              turboThreshold: 4000
              //label: {
              //    boostThreshold: 1,
              //    connectorAllowed: false
              //}
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Bitcoin',
          data: [
            [1562558400000, 29.9],
            [1562559400000, 50],
            [1562560400000, 80.9],
            [1562561400000, 100.9],
            [1562562400000, 10.9],
            [1562563400000, 30.9],
            [1562564400000, 50.9],
            [1562565400000, 29.9]
          ]
      }],

      responsive: {
          rules: [{
              condition: {
                  maxWidth: 500
              },
              chartOptions: {
                  legend: {
                      layout: 'horizontal',
                      align: 'center',
                      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                  }
              }
          }]
      },
      defs: {
          glow: {
              tagName: 'filter',
              id: 'glow',
              opacity: 0.1,
              children: [{
                  tagName: 'feGaussianBlur',
                  result: 'coloredBlur',
                  stdDeviation: 2.5
              }, {
                  tagName: 'feMerge',
                  children: [{
                      tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                      in: 'coloredBlur'
                  }, {
                      tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                      in: 'SourceGraphic'
                  }]
              }]
          }
      },
      credits: {
          enabled: false,
      }
  });
});







$("#Second").on("click", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
  var ETHstockChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container2', {
      time: {
          timezone: 'America/New_York'
      },
      chart: {
          styledMode: true
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Price',
              style: {
                  color: '#FFF'
              }
          },
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#b5ffb5'
              }
          }
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
              minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
              hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
              day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
              week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
              month: '%Y-%m',
              year: '%Y'
          },
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#b5ffb5'
              }
          }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
          allButtonsEnabled: true,
          inputEnabled: false,
          buttonSpacing: 8,
          labelStyle: {
              color: '#f7d3d3'
          },
          buttons: [{
              type: 'day',
              count: 1,
              text: '1D',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      ETHstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 70.9],
                          [1562559400000, 10],
                          [1562560400000, 50.9],
                          [1562561400000, 20.9],
                          [1562562400000, 100.9],
                          [1562563400000, 40.9],
                          [1562564400000, 60.9],
                          [1562565400000, 29.9]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          },{
              type: 'day',
              count: 3,
              text: '3D',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      ETHstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 74.9],
                          [1562559400000, 1],
                          [1562560400000, 30.9],
                          [1562561400000, 25.9],
                          [1562562400000, 29.9],
                          [1562563400000, 58.9],
                          [1562564400000, 29],
                          [1562565400000, 68.90]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          }, {
              type: 'all',
              text: 'All',
              events: {
                  click: function () {
                      ETHstockChart.series[0].update({
                        data: [
                          [1562558400000, 29.9],
                          [1562559400000, 50],
                          [1562560400000, 80.9],
                          [1562561400000, 100.9],
                          [1562562400000, 10.9],
                          [1562563400000, 30.9],
                          [1562564400000, 50.9],
                          [1562565400000, 29.9]
                        ]
                      },true);
                  }
              }
          }]
      },
      navigator: {
          enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
          enabled: false
      },

      legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },

      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              turboThreshold: 4000
              //label: {
              //    boostThreshold: 1,
              //    connectorAllowed: false
              //}
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Bitcoin',
          data: [
            [1562558400000, 29.9],
            [1562559400000, 50],
            [1562560400000, 80.9],
            [1562561400000, 100.9],
            [1562562400000, 10.9],
            [1562563400000, 30.9],
            [1562564400000, 50.9],
            [1562565400000, 29.9]
          ]
      }],

      responsive: {
          rules: [{
              condition: {
                  maxWidth: 500
              },
              chartOptions: {
                  legend: {
                      layout: 'horizontal',
                      align: 'center',
                      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                  }
              }
          }]
      },
      defs: {
          glow: {
              tagName: 'filter',
              id: 'glow',
              opacity: 0.1,
              children: [{
                  tagName: 'feGaussianBlur',
                  result: 'coloredBlur',
                  stdDeviation: 2.5
              }, {
                  tagName: 'feMerge',
                  children: [{
                      tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                      in: 'coloredBlur'
                  }, {
                      tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                      in: 'SourceGraphic'
                  }]
              }]
          }
      },
      credits: {
          enabled: false,
      }
  });
});
```

Can Someone help me out please?
Really appreciated!

Best regards,

Sida Zhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way of implementation. Lets analyze what's happening step by step.

First of all, you have the CSS style definition for `.highcharts-graph`, where the `filter: url(#glow);` is set on all elements with this class. That means, both of charts series have been searching for `#glow` element in the DOM tree, and both of them have the same `#glow` filter definition within configuration, so in sum, there are two elements in the DOM tree with the same `id`.

If you set the `display: none` on the first chart's container, it still exists in the DOM tree, but all of its children are also have `display: none`, including `#glow` element. Notice, that if browser is searching for the element with specific `id`, it always returns the first found element.

And here comes the problem source. As you've probably already understood, the `#glow` filter, which have the `display: none`, is set on the second chart's `.highcharts-graph` element, and that's why whole series line disappears right after changing the charts.

The best solution will be to change the `id`'s, so that they would be different (for example `#glow` and `#glow2`), and refactor the CSS, like below:

```css
#container .highcharts-graph {
  filter: url(#glow);
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

#container2 .highcharts-graph {
  filter: url(#glow2);
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qv4d3rax/

Kind regards!

Comment: By the way, i have another question. Can you help me out please?

Comment: If that question is related with above topic, of course I can, but please mark the answer.

Comment: Marked! Thank you!
So, if you take a look at this live example: jsfiddle.net/7avu8gsL/1 
When i click download Chart as PNG, JPEG, PDF, and SVG images from the exporting button, the chart result is very unreadable; i think it has something to do with the gradient background. Also, when i click "View in full screen" in IE, the chart does not resize to full size window somehow.